# Building the logic of enabling buttons

Tags: java, android, button

There are 4 buttons: 2 parent (s1 and s2) and 2 child (s3 and s4), as well as 2 states (on/off).

1. If s3 or s4 are enabled, then s1 is automatically enabled.
2. If s1 is off and s2 is on (and vice versa), then s3 and s4 remain on.
3. If the parent buttons are disabled, then the child buttons are also disabled.

Code to enable s1 using child buttons:

```
if (switch3.isChecked()){
           switch1.setChecked(true);
       }
       else{
           switch3.setChecked(false);
       }
        if (switch4.isChecked()){
            switch1.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            switch4.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us first handle the case which will make all other cases impossible. In this case, this would be if both parent switches are off. This would result in both child switches also being off. Then we check for condition 1 and then finally condition 2.
If something is `true`, a `!` in front of it would make it a `false`. The `!` is a negation operator, transforming a **boolean** value to its opposite. `&&` is **AND** performed between 2 expressions meaning result will only be `true` if both **AND-ed** expression values are `true`. `||` is **OR** performed between 2 expressions meaning result will only be `true` if both **OR-ed** expression values are either both `true`, or 1 `true` and another `false`. Now let us proceed. I didn't quite get condition 3 of your question as to whether they both have to be off at the same time or not. But this example is assuming both have to be off at the same time for condition 3 to be in effect.

```
if(!s3.isChecked() && !s4.isChecked())
{
  s1.setChecked(false);
  s2.setChecked(false);
}
else if(s3.isChecked() || s4.isChecked())
{
  s1.setChecked(true);
}
else if((!s1.isChecked() && s2.isChecked()) || (!s2.isChecked() && s1.isChecked()))
{
  s3.setChecked(true);
  s4.setChecked(true);
}
```

When performing multiple operations it is best to separate each portion using paranthesis.